# What does a License look like?

Tags: united-states, license

What does the HAM license look like?

Is it a card? A document?

All I could find on google is *ham radio license plates*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most purposes, there is no "official" paper license in the United States anymore. Your record in the FCC's online database is what gives you a license to operate. However, if you like, you may download and print a PDF from their system. It looks like this:

[image: FCC Amateur License Reference Copy]

except that, for your own license, you can download one that says "OFFICIAL COPY" instead of "REFERENCE COPY". As you can see, they provide cut-out marks for a certificate version that looks like it should fit a 5x6" frame, and a "wallet" version that folds to the size of a standard ID card. Each one provides a place for you to affix a signature if you would like.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed.